# Get id, name and number for a contact?

Tags: android

I have a "Contact" class and i'm using the standard contact picker code for Android but i want to get the "id" and the "name" of the contact too, not just the number... Here's my code.

```
@Override public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent ) {

    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, intent );
    if ( requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST ) {

        if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            Uri contactUri = intent.getData();
            String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);
            int contactNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);

            //i need to get the contactId and the contactName here

            Contact newContact = new Contact(contactId,contactName,contactNumber);

               EditText _contactName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
               _contactName.setText(number.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

I found the solution. Here it is if anyone needs it.

```
            Uri contactUri = intent.getData();
            String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone._ID};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(columnNumber);

            int columnName = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String contactName = cursor.getString(columnName);

            int columnID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone._ID);
            String ID = cursor.getString(columnID);
            int contactID = Integer.parseInt(ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question makes it clear you just found this code somewhere online.

Your `String[] projection` you can compare to 'SELECT...'  in a SQL query. 
Currently, you're only asking for Phone.NUMBER, so that's all you get.

I do not know at the top of my head what the constants are, but i guess you want something like;

```
String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER, Contact.NAME, Contact.ID};
```

From then on you can use the normal get methods to fetch this data, from your Contact object.

ps. I repeat, the constants are a guess. I'm sure you can find the exact ones yourself if they're not correct or even the IDE will simply help you with it with a dropdown.

Comment: Yes i'm following a tutorial (it's my first day of Java and programming for Android) and i'm confused by these proejctions, cursors etc ... Thanks btw!